# Does Django require the full web-setup to run professionally on non-internet devices?

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

This is either a really good or really stupid question, but I find its worth asking --

I'm making a Django app that runs on a device as an interfaces. Is there any reason to think I could just use the `python manage.py runserver` and go no further? Or is there a better way to do this?

Installing the full web-bundle for local-network-devices seems excessive, hence my question. (Perhaps there is not a great deal of overhead using the full-web-setup -- I dunno). This is currently on the Raspberry pi, but for prototype purposes. The end-product will not necessarily be Pi.

Comment: What do you mean by "run professionally"?

Comment: The `runserver` docs answer your first question rather clearly: "DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING."

Comment: By "run professionally" I mean have it run on a device that you'd use on a local area network -- a product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how many users you're expecting to connect at once. The Django development server is suitable for only one connection at a time. It isn't good at handling multiple sessions and is not designed to stay up for long periods of time. This is the reason the docs clearly state

> do not use this server in a production setting!

That said, running with an application server like [gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) may be all you need to support hosting multiple users. It uses multiple workers so that if one user's request crashes, it can continue serving all the other users.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

Finally, if you're serving up a lot of assets like images or videos, you should really have a full web server like Nginx to intercept asset URLs so they're not served through Django itself. Django should not be serving assets directly in production.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Great answer. With all of that, I had forgotten the "Do not use this in a production setting..." prompt.